# Dynamic Menus from JSON REST API using backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, marionette

I'm newbie in Backbone.js, Marionette.js, underscore.js and require.js frameworks.
I'm trying to build a dynamic menu by calling REST API which returns a JSON array format.

Here is my JSON response :-

```
[
{
    "id": "header",
    "menu":[
            {
            "id":"Home",
            "subMenu":[
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"About",
            "subMenu":[
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"Contact",
            "subMenu":[
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id":"About",
    "menu":[
        {
            "id":"123",
            "subMenu":[
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"456",
            "subMenu":[
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"789",
            "subMenu":[
            ]
        }
        ]
}
]
```

From above JSON, i created a collection model, from collection model am fetching each id and with corresponding menu array and pushing it in-to another array. 
Here is my code

```
return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
tempalte: headerTemplate,
events: {
},
onShow: function(){
    var headerMenu = [];
    var aboutMenu = [];
    var menuArrray = new ModelMenuArray();
    menuArrray.fetch({
        async:false,
        success: function(response) {                   
        var json = response.toJSON();                   
        $.each(json, function(inx, menuFeatures) {
            if(menuFeatures.id == "header")
            {
                headerMenu.push(menuFeatures);
            }
            else if(menuFeatures.id == "About")
            {
                aboutMenu.push(menuFeatures);
            }
            else
            {
                // something
            }
        });                     
    }   
});
```

in aboutus page, i have a sidebar menu with submenus for menu.
based on id, i need to add the menus for corresponding pages. For example: if the id is header, i need to add the menus in header part.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Issue has resolved by calling the functions from template helper to template. Thanks Seebuscuit.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out :)